# Programmatically change button style without CSS

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to program a Blazor WASM page in pure C#, without any Razor-HTML or CSS. Is there a way to:

1. Generate GUI items (eg. buttons, inputs) using Razor C# code just like I'd do in .cs files?
   Example of how I'd imagine it:

   `Button myButton = new Button();`
2. Can I change an item's style in pure C#? Eg.:

   `myButton.Style = new Style() { BackColor = 333333, BorderColor = 222222 };`
3. Is there documentation showing how to do this and other UI manipulations without HTML or CSS?

I've been googling for a few days and was only able to find different variantions of how to use CSS to change styles.

Comment: Certainly it's possible to do any of this, but it will be a sisyphean task.  Why do you not want to use razor files (intended to be expressed with HTML patterns) to generate what ultimately becomes an HTML DOM?

Comment: I'm mostly concerned about CSS which I don't want to use. And since I was trying to get rid of CSS I started to wonder if it would be possible to write purely in C#.

Comment: But you ultimately need to produce an HTML document object model.  Even if you avoid the use of literal CSS files, all the styling will _still be done_ via CSS, even if it's by directly setting CSS properties via Javascript.  I still don't understand the desire to avoid the foundational technologies of the output medium you are trying to participate in (HTML and CSS).  But leaving aside all that, what would you expect `Button myButton = new Button();` to actually do?  It's still going to have to render HTML and CSS in order to be a valid HTML document or component.

Comment: I love C# and I hate CSS and it's not important for me what the output technology will be. I just want to write my code in C# and I was hoping Blazor WASM would let me do that. Looks like MAUI might be finally able to deliver the 100% C# experience but it's not been even publicly released yet so Blazor is my best hope for now.

Comment: I love C# too and for a desktop or mobile app, I prefer the approach you are going for as well.  It's also an increasingly popular approach as evidenced by SwiftUI on iOS and Jetpack Compose on Android -- both of which are code-first UI toolkits with nary a trace of XML (a technology I loath).  However, Blazor is _explicitly_ a tech stack designed to produce HTML pages.  If you remove the web aspects of Blazor, you aren't actually left with anything at all.  Blazor is built on top of the WASM part of Mono, which is what enables Blazor to use web assembly.